# Adding markers on Google Map in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, coordinates

i have a bunch of coordinates in my model and want to add them to a Google Map, so every single coordinate is added to the map. How can I achieve this? Do I have to iterate through the object and add every single coordinate in the erb template?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you use the gem I developed: [gmaps4rails](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails).